# How to mute embeded youtube video? Volume = 0 doesn't work

Tags: javascript, youtube, mute

**volume=0** doesn't seem to be supported anymore. 
Does anyone know how i can mute my iframe now in year of 2017?

When i click unmute icon, mute icon should appear and video should be muted. (and the other way around) 
**This is what iv tried thus far:**

```
//Mute-Unmute Music
 $('#unmute').on('click', function() {
    $("#unmute").hide();
    $("#mute").show();
    $("#iframe").attr("volume", "0");
 });
 $('#mute').on('click', function() {
    $("#mute").hide();
    $("#unmute").show();
    $("#iframe").attr("volume", "1");
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any web page that uses the IFrame API must also implement the
>   following JavaScript function:
>
> onYouTubeIframeAPIReady – The API will call this function when the
>   page has finished downloading the JavaScript for the player API, which
>   enables you to then use the API on your page. Thus, this function
>   might create the player objects that you want to display when the page
>   loads.

So your code should look like this:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
   player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE'
     }
  });
}

$('#unmute').on('click', function() {
    $("#unmute").hide();
    $("#mute").show();
    player.mute();
});
$('#mute').on('click', function() {
    $("#mute").hide();
    $("#unmute").show();
    player.unMute()
});
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i actually have a playlist. When an option is clicked this playlist starts playing in the background. 

Can i just change videoId with playlist Id or something?

Comment: You can use player.loadPlaylist() method call. Please take a look here https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: or you can add player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      playerVars: 
          {
            listType:'playlist',
            list: '<YOURPLAYLISTID>'
          }  
     }
  });

Comment: Hey man, iv tried this but it doesn't seem to work. 
Can you check it out -> http://codepen.io/urketadic/pen/YpLgBX

Click options -> Enable Matrix  then try to mute the sound. It won't work.

Your code is located at the bottom of JS.  

(now iv saved it)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting me this atleast, il just make another question now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470533/youtube-api-muting-video-iframe

Comment: @The Garrus I answered you in the another question